tcl dict2json get quote in string
I don't understand the tcl json::dict2json if i have a simple dict that i would like to convert to json where the values have ".
set myDict [dict create key1 "v1" key2 "v2" key3 "v3"]
 
set jsonString [json::dict2json $myDict]
puts "$jsonString"

{"key1": v1
,"key2": v2
,"key3": v3
}

When i look at the TCL code "proc ::json::dict2json {dictVal}" it have this if that should create " on the value but it is always 0
if {0 && ![string is double -strict $val]
    && ![regexp {^(?:true|false|null)$} $val]} {

    set val "\"$val\""
}


In my experience, that JSON package is buggy. RL_JSON is much better if you can use it https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json

if {0 && ...}? That leading 0 means the expression is always going to be false.

You are right, the output is not a valid json. For that reason I am using my own implementation with additional enhancements.
